# USRP X310 not receiving anything but noise

Tags: gnuradio, frequency-modulation, usrp

I have been trying to receive different types of signals using a USRP X310 but all I can receive is noise. I tried different types of antennas and designed many different kinds of blocks but I get nothing but noise. In my recent attempts I have been trying to transmit and receive at the time so that I can make sure the reception is of a decent quality signal and there is no issue with multipath but even then all I can receive is noise. Here is the block diagram:

[image: Blocks]

The ports are green lit for reception and red lit for transmission as they should be I believe. I don't see any issue with the blocks. Any suggestions would be appreciated! If more information is needed then I can provide but for now I believe the problem lies somewhere in the blocks perhaps but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: your gain is extremely low. Also, we don't know which daughterboards you use.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I tried previously with various different gains and it did not make a difference. In terms of the frequency coverage, the range is 50MHz-2.2GHz

Comment: What is "various gains"? I ask because of changing gains does nothing, something is fundamentally wrong. Check `uhd_usrp_probe` for the possible gains you can set.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Just wanted to come back and say that the issue was with one of the daughterboards. So thank you for pointing me in that direction.